# Java collection grouping with custom key

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a list of students `studentList` and i want to seperate them based on their class and section into a `Map<CustomKey, List<Student>>`.

```
class Student {
public String Name;
public String Class;
public String Section;
}
```

I have a custom Key Class

```
class CustomKey {
public String Class;
public String Section;
}
```

I'm trying to group them using this, but we can clearly see what I'm doing wrong.

```
studentList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> new CustomKey(x.Class, x.Section)));
```

The expression inside groupingBy is incorrect.
Extending the Student Class is not allowed :(

I want to create this output

```
{
    {"ClassA", "SectionA"}: [{name, class, section}, {name, class, section}],
    {"ClassA", "SectionB"}: [{name, class, section}],
    {"ClassB", "SectionA"}: [{name, class, section}, {name, class, section}],
}
```

My knowledge is very limited on JAVA. And any help/pointers are welcomed.
Also, Apologies for the messed-up cases.

Comment: What makes it incorrect? Are you getting an error or unexpected output? Do you have the `CustomKey(String, String)` constructor that you're calling?

Comment: By the way, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are written in camelCase. Also, to improve encapsulation, you should make your fields `private`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `CustomKey` is matched by its `equals` method, which you don't have overridden. If you implement `equals` (and also `hashCode`) properly, then it'll work.

What's even better, is to create a *record* for `CustomKey`:

```java
public record CustomKey(String className, String section) { }
```

This'll let the compiler auto-generate its `equals` and `hashCode` implementations for free, as well as getters, the *canonical constructor* and the `toString` method. The above record definition is equivalent to this:

```java
public final class CustomKey {

    private final String className;
    private final String section;

    public CustomKey(String className, String section) {
        this.className = className;
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String className() {
        return className;
    }

    public String section() {
        return section;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof CustomKey ck
            && Objects.equals(className, ck.className)
            && Objects.equals(section, ck.section);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(className, section);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomKey[className=" + className + ", section=" + section + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i used your code exactly like below and it works for me

```
 public void testCustomGroupBy(){
    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    studentList.add(new Student("name_1","class_1","section_1"));
    studentList.add(new Student("name_2","class_1","section_1"));
    studentList.add(new Student("name_3","class_2","section_1"));
    studentList.add(new Student("name_4","class_2","section_2"));
    studentList.add(new Student("name_5","class_2","section_2"));
    Map<CustomKey, List<Student>> studentsBySection = studentList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> new CustomKey(x.getClassName(), x.getSection())));
    studentsBySection.entrySet().forEach(System.out::print);
}
```

create your pojo like below

```
class Student {
public String name;
public String className;
public String section;
// getters and setters

public Student(String name, String className, String section) {
    this.name = name;
    this.className = className;
    this.section = section;
}
```

}

```
class CustomKey {
public String className;
public String section;
// getters and setters

public CustomKey(String className, String section) {
    this.className = className;
    this.section = section;
}
```

}

output

```
CustomKey(className=class_2, section=section_2)=[Student(name=name_4, className=class_2, section=section_2), Student(name=name_5, className=class_2, section=section_2)]
CustomKey(className=class_2, section=section_1)=[Student(name=name_3, className=class_2, section=section_1)]
CustomKey(className=class_1, section=section_1)=[Student(name=name_1, className=class_1, section=section_1), Student(name=name_2, className=class_1, section=section_1)]
```